# Put ListView in/out of Expanded based on how big the ListView is going to be

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView that might be big / small, depends on result of API call. What I want to do is if the result is too big, put this ListView inside Expanded.

The client could be anything, phone or tab, all with different sizes, both horizontal and vertical orientation supported.

How do I detect the size of the ListView before it gets built?

```
if (MyListView.height > this.container.height) {  // ListView isn't built yet, so how can I know the size?
  return Expanded(child: MyListView);
}
return MyListView();

// MyListView is just a ListView inside a Container
```

Answer (score 0):

API calls should be made inside initState function so that you don't hit the endpoint with each rebuild. (which can happen many times) You can create an empty future object in your statefull widget and in the initState function assign your api call to the future object. In build method add a FutureBuilder widget to control the state of the api call. (loading, errors? etc.) Once you get the data just check the length of the list and depending on that you can decide what to do:

```
data.length < 20 ? MyListView() : Expanded (child: MyListView())
```

Comment: You are comparing it to data.length. Depending on the device size and orientation, the data.length that can fit into a screen differs, and I need to know the size of the MyListView ahead of time so I can know whether to wrap it inside Expanded or not.